# Morphia use for Scala

Tags: orm, scala, mongodb, morphia

Is it possible to use Morphia in Scala?

Are there any other lightweight ORMs for MongoDB that support scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Morphia** is just a persistence layer based on **mongo-java-driver** that uses annotation in a JPA-style for object mapping. It should perfectly work with Scala.

Among the "native" Scala drivers (worth to mention that all of them are also based on **mongo-java-driver**), [**Rogue** (developed by Foursquare)](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/01/21/rogue-a-type-safe-scala-dsl-for-querying-mongodb/) is the closest ideologically to **Morphia** (though it doesn't use annotations, which aren't considered to be Scala-idiomatic).

Comment: Although I liked Salat, Rouge was really helpful. In the end, I ended up using Morphia anyway.

Comment: We must use Lift if we want to use Rogue don't we?

Comment: Are there any performance issues or 'in-inefficiencies' in using a Java based driver for a Scala implementation? Just curious..

Comment: @imaginonic: logically thinking, there shouldn't—I don't think it matters if the JVM is calling code from what was originally a `.java` file vs a `.scala` file... but somebody with better insight could confirm.

Comment: @jpartogi: not Lift as in Lift the Web Framework; just `lift-record` will do.

Answer (score 7):

Check out Salat:

https://github.com/novus/salat

Salat uses pickled Scala signatures to serialize and deserialize case classes.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer "Mongo Scala Driver":

https://github.com/osinka/mongo-scala-driver

Comment: When can I find a complex demo of it? I tried a day, but still don't know how to save a `user refs many question` model.

Answer (score 0):

[Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) is probably much more approachable and has a (much) smoother learning curve, but it's crucial to realize that the **static type-safety and auto-completion** support [Rogue](https://github.com/foursquare/rogue) gives you when querying is really one level above Morphia—Morphia is only runtime safe, which they also admit right the [beginning of the README](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/README.md).

Compare:

```
val checkin: Option[Checkin] =
  Checkin where (_.venueid eqs id)
    and (_.userid eqs mayor.id)
    and (_.cheat eqs false)
    and (_._id after sixtyDaysAgo) 
    limit(1).get()
```

vs

```
Employee scottsBoss =
  ds.find(Employee.class).filter("underlings", scottsKey).get();
```

If you change any of the field names or query values to be incorrect, you'll get an immediate typing error, whereas Morphia will only throw an exception at runtime.

See http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/01/21/rogue-a-type-safe-scala-dsl-for-querying-mongodb/